# Find the maximum possible area of a rectangle (not square) with a perimeter of 56 feet?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

> Find the maximum possible area of a rectangle (not square)  with a perimeter of 56 feet such that it's  sides are integers ?

I know that the  rectangle with maximum area  is a square,  but  here the problem didn't want this case ,  what should I do?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken such a rectangle doesn't exists. I mean if such exists then you can always make it look more similar to a square and have a greater area then the first one.

Comment: No solution ...

Comment: Were you supposed to assume the sides are integers?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  Yes

Comment: If a condition of the problem is that the sides are integers, then you should edit that into the body of the question. People shouldn't have to scroll through the comments to find out what the actual question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the length and height of the rectangle be $L$ and $H$, respectively. Then the area is $LH$, and the perimeter is $2L+2H$, so we are trying to maximize $LH$ subject to $L+H=28$, with the additional conditions $L\ne H$ (since we're forbidden to use a square), and $L$ and $H$ are (positive) integers (not originally stated as part of the question, but mentioned in the comments). Let's see how many ways we can show that the maximum area is 195:

First, since we can't use a $14\times14$ square, common sense suggests we get as close to a square as possible, and that would be a $13\times15$ rectangle, with area 195. If "common sense" isn't rigorous enough for you, then

Second, we could note that the only possible values of $L$ are $1,2,3,\dots,27$, and we could find the areas corresponding to each of the 26 allowable values of $L$ (not 27, since 14 is not allowable), and look at those 26 areas, and see that 195 is the biggest. It's not all that much work, and you might learn something useful by actually doing all those calculations. But it doesn't scale well – if the perimeter were 56,000,000 instead of 56, you'd be in for more work than you'd care for. So,

Third, we could note that $LH=L(28-L)=-L^2+28L$ is a quadratic in $L$, with negative leading coefficient, so the graph of $A=-L^2+28L$ is a parabola opening downward, with its peak at $L=14,A=196$. The closer $L$ is to 14, the closer you get to the peak of the parabola, so the only question is whether to take $L=13$ or $L=15$ – and by the symmetry of the thing, it doesn't matter, either way you get the area 195. But maybe you haven't studied parabolas yet, so

Fourth, note that $Q^2-28Q=Q^2-28Q+196-196=(Q-14)^2-196$ (this is the technique called "completing the square"), so the area is $196-(L-14)^2$. This is bigger, the smaller $(L-14)^2$ is, so the smaller $|L-14|$ is, and the smallest $|L-14|$ can be is 1, and then the area is 195.

Well, I hope at least one of these four ways appeals to you.

Comment: Thanks very much for help

Comment: One way to express thanks here is to click in the check mark next to the answer, to indicate that you are "accepting" it (providing you are satisfied with the answer, and don't need any further clarification).

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{S}$$

Comment: $\sqrt {S}<14$  or $S <196$ ?